# JavaScript change style of a specific child div from another child div

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

Let's say that we have a loop which result 3 divs with other 4 divs inside each, like this:

```
<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to change the style css with javascript. How can I make something like this in javascript and work?

`document.getElementsByClassName('one')[2].document.getElementsByClassName('two')[3].style.cssText {...};`

I want to change the style css of the class `.two` from `child [3]` which is inside class `.one` from `child [2]`

Answer (score 3):

You were very close. A `HTMLElement` has - like `document` - a `.getElementsByClassName` method to select some of the child elements:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('one')[2].getElementsByClassName('two')[3].style.cssText = 'background-color: red';
```

```html
<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>
```

MDN: [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [`Element.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName).

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code -

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('one')[2]
parent.getElementsByClassName('two')[3].style.color = "blue";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you absolutely want to do this with JS, but just in case, here's a pure CSS approach :

```css
.one:nth-child(3) .two:nth-child(4){
  background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
   <div class="two">second class</div>
</div>
```

(`nth-child` is 1-based)